# Weblogic error when opening a jsp

Tags: weblogic

Anyone seen this error before? Just happens when trying to view a jsp page.
Using weblogic 10.3.0.

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.utils.JspRuntimeUtils.convertType(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at jsp_servlet._en.__entry._jsp__tag0(__entry.java:341)
        at jsp_servlet._en.__entry._jspService(__entry.java:164)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace>
```

**Edit**: using windows 7 with jdk 1.6.0.24

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to 10.3.3.0 and problem went away...